# How to scrape data from sciencedirect

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping

I want to scrape all data from sciencedirect by keyword.
I know that sciencedirect is program by ajax,
so the data of their page could't be extract directly via the
url of search result page.

[The page I want to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Xix.png)

I've find the json data from numerous requests in  Network area, in my view, I could get json data by this url of the request.But there are some error msg and garbled. Here is my code.

[The request that contain json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8temQ.png)

```
import requests as res
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

keyword="digital game"
url = 'https://www.sciencedirect.com/search/api?'

payload = {
    'tak': keyword, 

    't': 'ZNS1ixW4GGlMjTKbRHccgZ2dHuMVHqLqNBwYzIZayNb8FZvZFnVnLBYUCU%2FfHTxZMgwoaQmcp%2Foemth5%2FnqtM%2BGQW3NGOv%2FI0ng6yDADzynQO66j9EPEGT0aClusSwPFvKdDbfVcomCzYflUlyb3MA%3D%3D',

    'hostname': 'www.sciencedirect.com'

    }

r = res.get(url, params = payload)
print(r.content) # get garbled

r = r.json()
print(r) # get error msg
```

[Garbled (not json data I expect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbgyU.png)

[Error msg (about .json()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hARc4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the HTTP headers in the request such as *user-agent* to mimic a standard web browser. This will return query search results in JSON format.

```python
import requests

keyword = "digital game"
url = 'https://www.sciencedirect.com/search/api?'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    
payload = {
    'tak': keyword, 
    't': 'ZNS1ixW4GGlMjTKbRHccgZ2dHuMVHqLqNBwYzIZayNb8FZvZFnVnLBYUCU%2FfHTxZMgwoaQmcp%2Foemth5%2FnqtM%2BGQW3NGOv%2FI0ng6yDADzynQO66j9EPEGT0aClusSwPFvKdDbfVcomCzYflUlyb3MA%3D%3D',
    'hostname': 'www.sciencedirect.com'
    }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
# need to check if the response output is JSON
if "json" in r.headers.get("Content-Type"):
    data = r.json()
else:
    print(r.status_code)
    data = r.text
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'searchResults': [{'abstTypes': ['author', 'author-highlights'], 'authors': [{'order': 1, 'name': 'Juliana Tay'},
 ..., 'resultsCount': 961}}
```

Comment: thanks, but i still get a error msg about json, like this:
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @alienDog you need to inspect the r.status_code value. if not 200 then maybe the authorization token or payload is wrong. Is there a help page for the API?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. The point is that sciencedirect.com is using cloudflare which blocks the access for scraping bots. I've tried to use different approaches like cloudsraper, cfscrape etc... Unsuccessful! Then I've made a small parser based on Selenium which allows me to take metadata from publications and put it into my own json file with following schema:

```
schema = {
    "doi_number": {
        "metadata": {
            "pub_type": "Review article" | "Research article" | "Short communication" | "Conference abstract" | "Case report",
            "open_access": True | False,
            "title": "title_name",
            "journal": "journal_name",
            "date": "publishing_date",
            "volume": str,
            "issue": str,
            "pages": str,
            "authors": [
                "author1",
                "author2",
                "author3"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any questions or maybe ideas fill free to contact me.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you implemented Selenium. I cannot use it, as it gives me a login page, blocking access. Could you share some details?

Comment: This is pretty straight forward. 
You can find more details of using selenium library with python here [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
There are also some tips of usage